# Does ViewPager have any known issues?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using ViewPager without fragments, and need to support 2.1+ so I am using support library. Does anyone know if there are any crashing issues to be careful of?  Or any devices that do not work well with ViewPager?  I will be releasing this with thousands of downloads so i need to know if anyone knows of any issues.

Comment: I use ViewPager with ActionBarSherlock and Android Support Library and get sometimes weird errors, without reference to my own code. It's a bit of investigation to find the error. Thats the only problem I know.

Comment: What kind of Weird errors have you seen?

Comment: I use Crittercism Enterprise to monitor my apps and sometimes I get ViewPager stacktraces / exceptions without any reference to the actual code only to android.view or similar.

Comment: The errors are kinda rare. 
Not a argument to not to use ViewPager. I for myself never got a error, could be just a problem with a specific rarely used customization or something else. It's Android. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewPager` is used extensively throughout Google's own apps, so i think it's safe to say it's been vetted. and yes, those apps run on Android 2.1.

Comment: So you think it has high credibility? Which apps btw?

Comment: Nearly every app which support swipe in any way use ViewPager (for example YouTube, Google+, GMail and many more)

Comment: market. music. currents. also, i use it in our app (from the compat package).